# Custom HTML Dialog in Electron

Tags: html, dialog, electron

How (or is it even possible) to use custom HTML dialogs in Electron? I know that Electron provides certain dialogs (`showMessageDialog`, `showErrorDialog`) but these do not seem to allow custom HTML.

I do not wish to use native HTML dialogs (`dialog`) tag as it does not 'blend in' with the user interface.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a BrowserWindow that's modal and, if you like, frameless. See http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/.

Comment: Could I spawn the window from the main BrowserWindows' process?

Comment: Yes. The window (dialog) can be created from the main process. In the renderer process, you can do the same thing with window.open. See the docs: http://electron.atom.io/docs/. Everything you need is there.

Comment: The problem with modal windows in Electron is that there is a short flicker when its `.show()` function is called. There's actually an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10616) about this problem and I shared a [hacky solution](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10616#issuecomment-760641386) that I found.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.
On your parent you should have:

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote;
```

and then:

```
let child = new BrowserWindow({
        parent: remote.getCurrentWindow(), 
        modal: true, 
        width:300, height:300,
        webPreferences: {
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
child.loadFile('myCustomModal.html');
```

On myCustomModal.html remeber to include a way to close the modal!
like:

```
<button id="cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
<script>
 const remote = require('electron').remote;

  document.getElementById("cancel-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
       var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
       window.close();
  });   

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As [Marc Rochkind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39170346/9591441) said in a previous answer, you can use modal windows in Electron.

However, I have found a small bug with modal windows which causes the parent window to flicker for a very short duration when its `.show()` function is called. After quite some time on Google, I found an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10616) about the same problem. After reading the comment section in the issue, and stumbling across some code snippets, I shared a [hacky solution](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10616#issuecomment-760641386) in the issue's comment section.

It does take some work to set up, but once it's done, it's really easy to port to other child windows.