# Problems with Custom HTML Dialog in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialog, electron

So first off, I know about the following question *[Custom HTML Dialog in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170104/custom-html-dialog-in-electron)* already exists. My question expands on this question when some problems came up on the latest version of electron.

So some context:
I actually started a project of mine on like a very old version on Electron(`v2.0.5`) that I already had cuz I was too lazy to update electron. I got a working dialog class that you **could** do something like this:

```js
let dialog = new dialog_class("./pages/dialog.html")
dialog.display().then((response) => console.log(response));
```

However I had to update my version to the current(`v9.1.1`) so of course my dialog broke, but I can't figure out how/why.

I create my dialog very much like this:

```js
constructor(link){
    this.link = link;
    this.window = new electron.remote.BrowserWindow({...});
}
display(){
    return new Promise((callback)=>{
        this.window.loadURL(...);//url.format function in place of ...
        this.window.on(`close`, () => {
            if (!this.cancelCloseEvent) callback(false);
        });
    }
}
destroy(){
    this.window.closable = true;
    this.widow.close();
}
```

However, when I run this function:

```js
function openDialog(){
    let dialog = new dialog_class("./pages/dialog.html")
    dialog.display().then((response) => console.log(response));
}
```

I can open the dialog perfectly, but can *only* close the dialog *once*. Like I can open it, close it then open it again **but** can't close it again. When I try to close it a 2nd time it keeps the dialog open AND throws this:

```
electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:82 Uncaught TypeError: Object has been destroyed
    at BrowserWindow.get (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:125)
    at electron/js2c/browser_init.js:233
    at IpcMainImpl.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:233)
    at IpcMainImpl.emit (events.js:223)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:173)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:223)
```

I don't know why this happens, as each time I run `openDialog` it should create a NEW BrowserWindow, so I don't know how it's referencing the old window.

**Note:** all the code shown here *should* be enough for my problem. But just in case heres the entire `dialog_class`: https://pastebin.com/7pAwZJHF

## Edit:

Since I'm putting a bounty on this, I wanted people to be able to reproduce the issue. Heres all the code you'll need: https://github.com/Frustrated-Programmer/ElectronBug 
**However**: I still think all the code relevant is still supplied in this question

Comment: How are you closing your dialog?

Comment: via `dialog.destroy()` which get's called INSIDE the new BrowserWindow.

Comment: Since I couldn't edit my prev comment I'm replacing it with this one:  Inside the dialog the dialog closes itself by returning data and when the dialog_class receives the data it destroys the window and callbacks the data,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dialog.js`

```
display(context) {
        return new Promise((cb) => {
            electron.ipcRenderer.on("callback", (event, val) => {
                this._cancelCloseEvent = true;  
                cb(val);
                // this.destroy(); WRONG!!! Remove this and destory your window on test.js which is having this object instance
            });
        }
        ...
```

`test.js`

```
dialog.display().then(function(value) {
    response.innerText = value;
    dialog.destroy();
    // dialog = null; unnecessary!
});
```

Comment: OML I've spent so much time on this... Maybe you could explain to me why this works? Each time I open a dialog I start everything with a `new`. `new dialog_class` and `new BrowserWindow`. Why does destroying it from the outside work instead of destroying itself from the inside? *ALSO* is there any way I could destroy it from the inside, as I rather have a single `.destroy` then a `.destroy` every time I use a dialog.

Comment: @Frustratedprogrammer maybe you change `this.destroy()` to `this.window.destroy()` as  you are creating the browser as `closeable: false`